# Text search and distinct in objectify

Tags: java, objectify

Want to do free text search in objecify and do distinct, my situation is like this:

```
1) NamedTrivialNew class:

        public class NamedTrivialNew implements Serializable {

            private String title;
            private String city;
            ...
        }

public class KeyWord  implements Serializable { 
    @Id
    public Long id; 
    @Parent
    public Key<NamedTrivialNew> reason;  

    public KeyWord(){       
    }
```

3)

```
Search filter class:



    NamedTrivialNew n = new NamedTrivialNew();
                n.setSomeString("search test");
                KeyWord hp = new KeyWord();
                hp.reason = Key.create(NamedTrivialNew.class, 123L);
                hp.id = 456L;

                Key<KeyWord> hpKey = ofy().save().entity(hp).now();
                ofy().clear();
                assert ofy().load().key(hpKey).now() != null;

  QueryResultIterator<KeyWord> NamedTrivialNew  = ofy().load().type(KeyWord.class).filter("keyword>=", "search").filter("keyword <=", "search\uFFFD").iterator();
```

I am following this sample:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/Uc6_f98Tuao

Iterable reasons = ofy.query(Keyword.class).filter("keyword

> =", "basic").filter("keyword <=", "basic\uFFFD").fetchParents();

There is no method: fetchParents();

i have tried above sample but it is not working....

Comment: It is really, hard to understand what you get currently. Could provide more code for search filter or some info on this. What is object 'ofy'? What does it do? How does its 'list' method implemented.

Comment: You can just list the entities and get the parent keys back out of the results, or store the parent as a ref. I would also recommend using the full text search service over trying to roll your own using ofy. Eventually the composite indexes will get out of hand.

Comment: thanks nick..made workaround it did nt help..